# Как организовать архитектуру блока визуализации с элементами внутри с использованием MVC?

Tags: веб-программирование, canvas, mvc

Т.е. есть вывод (canvas - html5). Нужно в нем рисовать блоки реагирующие на их наведение.
Элемент вывода, как я понимаю, должен быть тоже построен на MVC, ну и блоки в нем само собой.

Но тогда два вопроса:

1) В модели блока визуализации необходимо хранить ссылки на модели блоков? Или на объекты включающие в себя совокупность модели, представления и контроллера каждого блока?

2) Кому передавать координаты мыши из представления блока визуализации для последующей проверки на пересечение с фигурой блока? Т.е. у меня проблема с тем, что необходимо оповещать блоки о перемещении мыши в их контейнере (canvas), а это создает взаимодействия между двумя разными сущностями (canvas и блоком).

Спсибо.

Comment: Не стоит городить mvc ради mvc.

Comment: Canvas и события? Предлагаю попробовать SVG

Comment: >Не стоит городить mvc ради mvc.
Я бы с удовольствием, но того требует начальство((

>Canvas и события? Предлагаю попробовать SVG
Приходится работать с канвой также желание начальства...